# Dim myConn As ADODB.Connection

Tags: vba, excel, ibm-midrange

I am trying a couple of things and one is to connect an excel workbook with an AS400 to get the description to a part number in our system but trying to keep the connection open or at least until the workbook is closed.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Public Sub GetPartNumbers()

    Dim myConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim myRS As ADODB.Recordset
''    Dim selVal As String
''    Dim selRow As Integer
    Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
    myConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SEQUEL ViewPoint;"
    myConn.Open
    Set myRS = New ADODB.Recordset
```

Comment: You should edit your title and provide something that actually relates to what you're trying to do. It's currently just a line of code. Also, what are you asking about? Connecting to an AS400, or keeping the connection open? If keeping the connection open, why?

Comment: Hi Lynn,  Never used this site before and now trying to find out how to edit the title .    The reason I need the connection open is that I have a control button and every time the are on a particular cell the would click the command button and it will bring in the information from the iSeries.  the problem is that the don't want to sing in to the system every time they click the button and if I can leave the connection open as long as the workbook is open that would work perfectly.   Very new to this type of programming  Thank you for your reply ..   awesome place by the way

Comment: Hi Jaime, click the Edit link to edit the question and/or the title.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it.

```
Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim myRs As New ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

con.Open "PROVIDER=IBMDAS400;Data Source=999.999.999.999;USER ID= ;PASSWORD= ;"

Set myRs.ActiveConnection = myConn

End

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Can not connect", vbInformation, cHeading
End

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try that Phil652 .  Thank you so much ..   Very new to this VB coding....    awesome

Comment: I edited out the profanity in the error handler - same idea, just changed the name. Feel free to re-edit it to whatever :)

Comment: Thank you for your edit. @JaimeHernandez feel free to ask any question

Comment: I will keep you posted..   You guys have an  awesome thanksgiving.

Answer (score 0):

I can sympathize with you as I had to figure this out as well before I knew much about VBA.  Below is a simple connection and loop through results example.  And yes, you shouldn't use Activate but for the sake of this example I through it in.

Note that you should clean up the connection at the end.  If you use an error handler than make sure you close any open connections before exiting even after an error.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open "PROVIDER=IBMDAS400;Data Source=999.999.999.999;USER ID= ;PASSWORD= ;"
rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer

'Query String (Specific to your database setup)
rst.Source = "SELECT DISTINCT F3002.IXLITM " _
                & "FROM WYATT.PRDDTA.F3002 F3002 " _
                & "WHERE (F3002.IXKITL='30P') AND (F3002.IXTBM='E')"

rst.Open

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Activate

Do Until rst.EOF
    ActiveCell.Value = rst.Fields("IXLITM")

    rst.MoveNext
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop

'Clean up
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```